# powershell hashtable (export-Csv) to CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, authentication, audit

The following code in powershell creates a file with key/value pairs.

```
$result = @()
Get-EventLog -LogName Security -After ((Get-Date).AddDays(-5)) -InstanceId 4624 |
ForEach-Object {
if ($_.ReplacementStrings[5] -ne "SYSTEM")
   {
       $result += [PSCustomObject]@{
           Time = $_.TimeGenerated
           Workstation = $_.ReplacementStrings[11]
       }
   }
 }
#$result | Export-Csv -Path .\Logins.csv -NoTypeInformation
$result | Out-File "C:\Temp\Logins.csv"
```

The above results in the following file contents:

[image]

However, I want the contents in CSV format. If I change the commented lines out as below:

```
$result = @()
Get-EventLog -LogName Security -After ((Get-Date).AddDays(-5)) -InstanceId 4624 |
 ForEach-Object {
   if ($_.ReplacementStrings[5] -ne "SYSTEM")
   {
       $result += [PSCustomObject]@{
           Time = $_.TimeGenerated
           Workstation = $_.ReplacementStrings[11]
       }
   }
 }
$result | Export-Csv -Path .\Logins.csv -NoTypeInformation
#$result | Out-File "C:\Temp\Logins.csv"
```

Then I get the following:
[image]

Googling around through myriad pages and examples, I (mis?)understand this to be a hashtable and that the Export-Csv should work to create a csv file. I cannot seem to get it to work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That output is not from the code you show.. Are you looking at the actual created file?

Comment: The "file" is the same file generated by the same script with the exception of the very last line. The two files are named with extension ".CSV". One generated with "Out-File" and the other generated with "Export-Csv". Both are acting on the same "$result". variable.

Comment: No, your code creates an array of `[PsCustomObject] s`. Your output shows an array of Hashtables

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm ... the following code works exactly like I'd expect it:

```
$result = 
Get-EventLog -LogName Security -After ((Get-Date).AddDays(-5)) -InstanceId 4624 |
ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.ReplacementStrings[5] -ne "SYSTEM") {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Time        = $_.TimeGenerated
            Workstation = $_.ReplacementStrings[11]
        }
    }
}
$result | Export-Csv -Path .\Logins.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

BTW: It is recommended not to use `Get-Eventlog` anymore. Use `Get-WinEvent` instead.  ;-)

Comment: using this, I only get the very last entry and the csv is still not an actual CSV. it seems the += is required to append current for each result to the previous foreach results.

Comment: No. `+=` is not required. Again. I just get the expected result with this exact code snippet in an elevated console. 2 Colums ...  `Time` and `Workstation`.

Comment: We must be using different versions or configuration of PS as copy/pasting your code into my elevated PS console and executing it results in the same contents in the resulting file. The results seem to be the metadata of the hashtable. I found a similar issue on GH 'https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10999'

Comment: But there is no hastable in my code snippet. It is a `[PSCustomObject]`

Comment: IDK Olaf. The GH link is also using [PSCustomObject].

Comment: Make sure you read up on the use case/differences/sameness of [HT and PSCO](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell+hashtable+vs+pscustomobject%27&t=h_&ia=web).

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be just this:

```
Clear-Host
$result = @()
Get-EventLog -LogName Security -After ((Get-Date).AddDays(-1)) -InstanceId 4624 |
ForEach-Object {
if ($_.ReplacementStrings[5] -ne "SYSTEM")
   {
       $result += [PSCustomObject]@{
           Time        = $PSItem.TimeGenerated
           Workstation = $PSItem.ReplacementStrings[11]
       }
   }
 }

$result | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Out-File -FilePath 'Logins.csv'
Get-Content -Path 'Logins.csv'
# Results
<#
"Time","Workstation"
...
"06-Aug-22 16:45:37","-"
"06-Aug-22 16:45:17","-"
"06-Aug-22 16:44:29","-"
...
 #>
```

***Update as per my comment.***

The results are the same as the above, either to the screen or the file:

```
Clear-Host
(Get-EventLog -LogName Security -After ((Get-Date).AddDays(-1)) -InstanceId 4624) -ne 'SYSTEM' | 
Select-Object -Property @{Name = 'Time';Expression = {$PSItem.TimeGenerated}},
                        @{Name = 'Workstation';Expression = {$PSItem.ReplacementStrings[11]}} | 
Export-Csv -Path 'Logins.csv'
Get-Content -Path 'Logins.csv'
```

Comment: Same result in "CSV". Seems the result is the properties of the variable's contents (hashtable ellement properties if you will) and not the values.

Comment: this errors out if pasted to my elevated PS console.

Comment: '@elcuartomago', what you are seeing is my response, is the live output to the code to the screen and to the file. If you step thru the code, to just the results, view the results, then to the convert statement, view the results, then the file. It's how I build scripts. Don't move forward until you know the previous step worked. As per '@Olaf', you really don't need the array statement at all. You could have used PS calculated properties to simplify this.

Comment: Copy/paste from a website often brings over non-printable/visible stuff, which causes failure. As a rule, never copy/paste and run code from any website. It not only can fail, but it's dangerous. In a sandbox, bring that code in an editor for review before you run it.

Comment: I can post the result of the pre-update code on my machine. It will not run unless I replace "$PSItem"  with "$_". How/where should I post code and result? Note that I ran the scripts on a server 2016 running PSVersion 5,1,1 and the results are as y'all say they should be. The same script executed on PSVersion 2 exhibits the result I'm describing.

Comment: PSv2, really? You did not say that was your environment in your initial post. That would have been really helpful before we all tried to assist. So, you can bet virtually everyone who'd respond is on 5x or PSCore, and would have never guessed you'd be on v2. This also explains why the suggestion '@Olaf' gave ***BTW: It is recommended not to use Get-Eventlog anymore. Use Get-WinEvent instead. ;-)***;  was not used. Now, that being said, I do not have any systems with PSv2, so no way to test what you are doing. Question why are you still using PSv2? This says you are on old Windows OS.

Comment: Notice that even in the [MS-provided docs, the furthest you can go back is v3.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/powershell/scripting/overview?view=powershell-7.1)

Comment: First: I appreciate the help and learning. My bad. IDK until after all the googling around and interactions with you all here that this was an issue. I am playing the cards I'm dealt. To the other question as to why use Get-Eventlog for this particular problem? Because, I found an extremely helpful example of how to pull these event utilizing Get-EventLog. That example didn't output to file. No problem.....or so I thought. Note that Substituting Get-WinEvent for Get-Eventlog in Olaf's example throws an error on this system so It seems there's more to it that just "Use Get-WinEvent instead";-)